# Create object from Gson string doesn't work

Tags: android, json, gson

I want to pass an object to a bundle. Now I did the conversion to a Json object with GSON.

The bundle is passed, the bundle has the right string representation but when I create the object from the string I get a huge error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private android.net.Uri() with no args
            at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:107)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:162)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
            at com.test.fragment.QFragment.onCreateView(QFragment.java:54)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1788)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:899)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1101)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:688)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1559)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:445)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class android.net.Uri
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:104)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:162)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
            at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
            at com.test.fragment.QFragment.onCreateView(QFragment.java:54)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1788)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:899)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1101)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:688)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1559)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:445)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm doing the conversion like this:

```
public static QFragment newInstance(FModel oModel) {
    QFragment fragment = new QFragment();
    fragment.mOModel = oModel;
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle();
    bdl.putString("oModel", new Gson().toJson(oModel));
    fragment.setArguments(bdl);
    return fragment;
}
```

and in my fragment on the createView:

```
 String jsonMyObject = null;
        Bundle args = this.getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            jsonMyObject = args.getString("oModel");
        }
        mOrderModel = new Gson().fromJson(jsonMyObject, FModel.class);
```

Whats the best way to fix this? Do I need to change to serializable or parcelable?

Comment: You are doing it right the problem is elsewhere,  Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class android.net.Uri,or your model class variabales have different names from the json keys ? But usually for me it gaves null when refering to the getters value not an error...

Comment: I don't have a class android.net.Uri?

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the relevant ctors and properties etc. in your FModel class.

Comment: Does Fmodel have Android.net.Uri field ? Android.net.Uri is abstract, by definition it cannot be instantiated.

Comment: Basically this is what we were all guessing, but the OP wouldn't post the code!!!! Well done OP anyway.

Comment: You can also use the BundleTypeAdapter as described here: https://github.com/google-gson/typeadapters/blob/master/android/src/main/java/BundleTypeAdapterFactory.java

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Found the problem in the FModel there was indeed a Uri.

Solved this by writing:

```
public class UriSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Uri> {
    public JsonElement serialize(Uri src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());
    }
}

public class UriDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Uri> {
    @Override
    public Uri deserialize(final JsonElement src, final Type srcType,
                           final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return Uri.parse(src.getAsString());
    }
}
```

and doing the Gson conversion like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Uri.class, new UriSerializer())
                .create();
        bdl.putString("oModel",gson.toJson(oModel));
```

and in the oncreate to rebuild this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapter(Uri.class, new UriDeserializer())
                    .create();
            jsonMyObject = args.getString("oModel");
            mOrderModel = gson.fromJson(jsonMyObject, FModel.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, really helpful but I still have a question. What happen when your object the one you are saving as JSON sometimes has the URI parameter set to null? In that case when is trying to write it will throw an exception. I've tried to check for null but then I get another error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19):

FYI, you can use serialize and deserialize at the same time by combining your two interfaces implementations into a single class.

```
public class UriInOut implements JsonSerializer<Uri>, JsonDeserializer<Uri> {
  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(Uri src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    return new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());
  }

  @Override
  public Uri deserialize(final JsonElement src, final Type srcType,
                         final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    return Uri.parse(src.getAsString());
  }
}
....
new GsonBuilder()   
    .registerTypeAdapter(Uri.class, new UriInOut())
    .create();
```

Comment: change src.getAsString() to src.toString()

Answer (score 13):

You can also use TypeAdapter which is [more efficient](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/)

```
public final class UriAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Uri> {
  @Override 
  public void write(JsonWriter out, Uri uri) throws IOException {
    out.value(uri.toString());
  }

  @Override 
  public Uri read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    return Uri.parse(in.nextString());
  }
}
```