# Serialize android.net.Uri object

Tags: android, serialization

I want to serialize the state of an object of type android.net.Uri.

Below is my model class with writeObject and readObject methoods

```
public class ReminderObject implements Serializable {
private boolean isReminderOn;
private int fromHours, toHours;
private int interval;
private ArrayList<CharSequence> daysToRepeat;
private Uri toneToPlay;
private AdvanceSettingsObject adv;

public ReminderObject(boolean isReminderOn, int fromHours, int toHours,
        int interval, ArrayList<CharSequence> daysToRepeat, Uri toneToPlay,
        AdvanceSettingsObject adv) {
    super();
    this.isReminderOn = isReminderOn;
    this.fromHours = fromHours;
    this.toHours = toHours;
    this.interval = interval;
    this.daysToRepeat = daysToRepeat;
    this.toneToPlay = toneToPlay;
    this.adv = adv;
} 
/*
getters and setters
*/
    public void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream op){
    try {
        op.defaultWriteObject();
        op.writeChars(toneToPlay.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void readObject(ObjectInputStream in){
    try{
        in.defaultReadObject();
        toneToPlay = Uri.parse(in.readUTF());
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}

}
```

Code snippet for MainActivity:

```
try {
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new     FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/ReminderData.txt")    );
        os.writeObject(reminder); // Getting above mentioned Exception here
        Log.i("TAG","reminder serialized");
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/ReminderData.txt"));
        ReminderObject reminderRead = (ReminderObject) is.readObject();
        if(reminderRead!=null)
            Log.i("TAG", "Deserialized Reminder object is : "+reminderRead.toString());
        else{
            Log.i("TAG", "Null received");
        }
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf){
        cnf.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {     
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Exception faced :

`03-31 23:47:59.246: W/System.err(12681): java.io.NotSerializableException: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri
03-31 23:47:59.246: W/System.err(12681):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1364)
03-31 23:47:59.246: W/System.err(12681):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
03-31 23:47:59.246: W/System.err(12681):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
03-31 23:47:59.246: W/System.err(12681):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
03-31 23:47:59.246: W/System.err(12681):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:979)
03-31 23:47:59.246: W/System.err(12681):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:368)
03-31 23:47:59.246: W/System.err(12681):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1074)
03-31 23:47:59.246: W/System.err(12681):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1404)
03-31 23:47:59.246: W/System.err(12681):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1671)
03-31 23:47:59.246: W/System.err(12681):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1517)
03-31 23:47:59.246: W/System.err(12681):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
03-31 23:47:59.246: W/System.err(12681):    at com.navkar.navkarreminder.SetReminderActivity.scheduleReminder(SetReminderActivity.java:595)`

Requesting help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As i think problem is the  data member that you saving problem .

`private Uri toneToPlay` is a non serialize data type and you cannot serialize it.

Comment: Yes, the Uri is not serializable, so I changed it to String.

Comment: donot forget to mark the answer solve.it helps other to find the answer.

Comment: `Uri` **is serializable!** Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533432/create-object-from-gson-string-doesnt-work

Answer (score 11):

URI `private Uri toneToPlay` is not serializable. So there is an alternative way, you can change the data type URI to String and convert your URI to string and string to URI while use in vise versa.

**Uri to String**

```
Uri uri;
String stringUri;
stringUri = uri.toString();
```

**String to Uri**

```
Uri uri;
String stringUri;
uri = Uri.parse(stringUri);
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `java.net.URI` class instead. This has almost the same functionality, but it's **`Serializable`**. You can easily convert from Uri to URI (and backwards):

**Uri to URI**: `new URI(uri.toString())`

**URI to Uri**: `Uri.parse(uri.toString())`

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions, when we want to still keep Uri as a member (for example for convenience) and serialize class is to make Uri `transient` and serialize `Uri String` (in the way @King of Masses showed).

This way we do not change public interface of our POJO, and we do not serialize Uri, creating it a lazy way.

Serializable POJO with Uri can look like this:

```
class MediaFile implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -420L;    

    @Nullable
    private transient Uri mFileUri;

    @NonNull
    private String mFileUriString;

    MediaFile(@NonNull Uri fileUri) {
        this.mFileUriString = fileUri.toString();
    }

    @NonNull
    public getFileUri() {
        if (mFileUri == null) {
            mFileUri = Uri.parse(mFileUriString);
        }
        return mFileUri;
    }


}
```

For kotlin:

```
class MediaFile(uri: Uri) : Serializable {
    private val mUriString = uri.toString();
    @Transient private val mUri by lazy { Uri.parse(mUriString) }
}
```