# Android: Failed to invoke private android.net.Uri() with no args

Tags: java, android, gson, sharedpreferences

I am saving my arraylist of custom model into shared preference using Gson

Storing code:

```
ArrayList<DownloadProgressDataModel> arrayList = getArrayListFromPref(downloadProgressDataModel);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = getSharedPreferences("APPLICATION_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(arrayList);
        prefsEditor.putString("DownloadManagerList", json);
        prefsEditor.apply();
    }
```

Retrieving

```
ArrayList<DownloadProgressDataModel> arrayList;
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("APPLICATION_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String json = mPrefs.getString("DownloadManagerList", "");

        if (json.isEmpty()) {
            arrayList = new ArrayList<DownloadProgressDataModel>();
        } else {
            Type uriPath = new TypeToken<ArrayList<DownloadProgressDataModel>>() {
            }.getType();
            arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, uriPath);  <------ Error line
        }
```

But on the error line I'm getting: ***can't instantiate class android.net.Uri***

Model

```
public class DownloadProgressDataModel {
    private Uri uriPath;
    private long referenceId;

    public Uri getUriPath() {
        return uriPath;
    }

    public void setUriPath(Uri uriPath) {
        this.uriPath = uriPath;
    }

    public long getReferenceId() {
        return referenceId;
    }

    public void setReferenceId(long referenceId) {
        this.referenceId = referenceId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe somebody will find this solution useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/22535258/13269710

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Uri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) class constructor is private and it's an abstract class. Gson tries to create a new object for the `Uri` class using Reflection API(We can't create an object for abstract class). So simple solution is to change the `uriPath` into `String` instead of `Uri`.

```
 private String uriPath;
```

Answer (score -1):

meh, just **exclude** the **problematic instance variable(s)** from 
the serialization/deserialization process. [Gson: How to exclude specific fields from Serialization without annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations)