# How to load data class that include MutableList<Uri> from SharedPreference?

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use SharedPreference and error occur when i load data. I think the problem is that my data class include MutableList, but i don't know how to handle it.

```
private lateinit var albumData:MutableList<Album>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    loadData()

    connectAdapter()

    btnAddAlbum.setOnClickListener {
        if(isStoragePermitted()) {
            openGallery()
        }
    }
}

fun saveData() {
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
    val json = gson.toJson(albumData)
    editor.putString("Album data", json)
    editor.apply()
}

fun loadData() {
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
    val json = sharedPreferences.getString("Album data", null)
    var test = mutableListOf<Album>()
    if(json != null) {
        Log.d("Log_show", "data load 1")
        val type = object : TypeToken<MutableList<Album>>() {}.type
        Log.d("Log_show", "data load 2")
        albumData = gson.fromJson<MutableList<Album>>(json, type)
        Log.d("Log_show", "data load 3")
    }else{
        albumData =  mutableListOf()
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    saveData()
    Log.d("Log_show", "shut down")
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

Above is part of my functions in main activity.

```
data class Album (
    var albumImages : MutableList<Uri>,
    var albumTitle : String,
    var pictureCount : Int
)
```

This is my data class "Album"

When i first open the app, it save data well and no error occur.
But when i close the app and open it again, the error occur in process of loading data
This is part of my log of "Log_show" and "data load 3" didn't appear

2020-11-04 23:12:33.418 15720-15720/kr.co.ddophi.autochangingwallpaper D/log: data load 1
2020-11-04 23:12:33.420 15720-15720/kr.co.ddophi.autochangingwallpaper D/log: data load 2

the full log is like this

> 2020-11-05 14:48:19.319 6956-6956/kr.co.ddophi.autochangingwallpaper D/Log_show: data load 1
> 2020-11-05 14:48:19.321 6956-6956/kr.co.ddophi.autochangingwallpaper D/Log_show: data load 2
> 2020-11-05 14:48:19.331 6956-6956/kr.co.ddophi.autochangingwallpaper D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
> 2020-11-05 14:48:19.336 6956-6956/kr.co.ddophi.autochangingwallpaper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: kr.co.ddophi.autochangingwallpaper, PID: 6956
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kr.co.ddophi.autochangingwallpaper/kr.co.ddophi.autochangingwallpaper.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private android.net.Uri() with no args
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private android.net.Uri() with no args
> at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:113)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
> at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
> at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
> at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
> at kr.co.ddophi.autochangingwallpaper.MainActivity.loadData(MainActivity.kt:174)
> at kr.co.ddophi.autochangingwallpaper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:43)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class android.net.Uri
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
> at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:110)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212) 
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41) 
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82) 
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) 
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131) 
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222) 
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41) 
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82) 
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) 
> at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927) 
> at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892) 
> at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841) 
> at kr.co.ddophi.autochangingwallpaper.MainActivity.loadData(MainActivity.kt:174) 
> at kr.co.ddophi.autochangingwallpaper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:43) 
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183) 
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Please in general include code snippets as code blocks instead of including only screenshots. Additionally could you please include the exact exception message and stack trace please?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I edit main text and add log message.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/46031104; Gson cannot create an instance of URI because it is an `abstract` class. You could either switch to `String` or write a [`TypeAdapter`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) which uses `URI.toString()` and `URI.parse(...)`. I can provide an example, but only in Java (maybe it is helpful nonetheless).

Comment: Oh, that's nice idea. I'll try that method. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should custom TypeAdapter for serialize and deserialize Uri.

```
class UriTypeAdapter : TypeAdapter<Uri>() {
    override fun write(out: JsonWriter?, value: Uri?) {
        value?.let {
            out?.value(it.toString())
        } ?: run {
            out?.nullValue()
        }
    }

    override fun read(reader: JsonReader?): Uri {
        return if (reader?.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            reader.nextNull()
            Uri.EMPTY
        } else {
            val uriString = reader?.nextString()
            uriString?.let {
                Uri.parse(it)
            } ?: run {
                Uri.EMPTY
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and setup Gson like this:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Uri::class.java, UriTypeAdapter())
    .create()
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I'll apply it usefully!