# Issue in retrofit 2.3.0 response getting in On-failure

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-layout

How can we solve this issue in retrofit 2.3.0;

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 3 column 1 path $
         09-28 15:03:54.910 8321-8321/com.travel.musafren W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
         09-28 15:03:54.910 8321-8321/com.travel.musafren W/System.err:     at
 com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)
        09-28 15:03:54.910 8321-8321/com.travel.musafren W/System.err:     at
 com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
         09-28 15:03:54.910 8321-8321/com.travel.musafren W/System.err:     at
retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
         09-28 15:03:54.910 8321-8321/com.travel.musafren W/System.err:     at
 retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
         09-28 15:03:54.910 8321-8321/com.travel.musafren W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
        09-28 15:03:54.910 8321-8321/com.travel.musafren W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
         09-28 15:03:54.910 8321-8321/com.travel.musafren W/System.err:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:112)
        09-28 15:03:54.910 8321-8321/com.travel.musafren W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:141)
         09-28 15:03:54.910 8321-8321/com.travel.musafren W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
         09-28 15:03:54.910 8321-8321/com.travel.musafren W/System.err:     at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
         09-28 15:03:54.910 8321-8321/com.travel.musafren W/System.err:     at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
         09-28 15:03:54.910 8321-8321/com.travel.musafren W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

JSON array schema is like this,

```
  [ "Currency": "INR", "Hotels": [ { "HotelName": "TAJ" } ]
```

Here, I am using GsonConvertfactory.create()

Comment: Please write your JSON array, it was not written.

Comment: [   "Currency": "INR",
        "Hotels": [
            {
                "HotelName": "TAJ" }  ]

Comment: I think in this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533432/create-object-from-gson-string-doesnt-work/22535258), you may get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Json parsing error. Please change `Hotels` to object or the response to object and check, it will work.